# Create an email alert in TFS/VSTS when a query returns a certain count of items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I can create basic queries in TFS or VSTS to return a list of all active bugs, what I want to do is if this count is greater than say 10, it sends me an email. Is this possible?

i.e more than 10 items with a work item type of Bug, in my area path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native way to accomplish that. However, you can easily use the REST APIs to query that information and do whatever you'd like with it.

You can also pin a query to your team's dashboard with optional color change rules, so a tile is displayed in a neutral color when bugs are < 10, but the tile turns red when it's >= 10.

Comment: Thanks got the tile working, is there some documentation for the REST APIs?

Comment: you can refer this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview